# trapping signals inside grouping commands

Tags: bash, trap

I recently ran into a strange behavior. Trap doesn't get executed if inside grouping command:

```
$ cat ./1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
trap 'echo exit' EXIT
$ ./1.sh
exit
$ cat ./2.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
echo test | { trap 'echo exit' EXIT; }
$ ./2.sh
```

Is it as it's supposed to be?

Comment: See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=698411 It's been fixed since.

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm it works in `bash-4.3.8`, and doesn't work in `bash-4.2.37`. If you answer my question, I'll accept it. Also, it'd interesting to know in which version/commit it was fixed. The bug report you mentioned doesn't tells anything about it.

Comment: If you or anyone else want to do, please feel free. See the bash Changelog for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=698411) that has been fixed somewhere between versions `>4.2.37` and `<=4.3.8`. Here is supposedly relevant information from [the changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.3-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-4.2-release.
>
> ...
>
> sss. Fixed a bug that caused asynchronous group commands to not run any EXIT
>        trap defined in the body of the command.
>
> ...
>
> tttt. Fixed a problem that caused subshells to not run an EXIT trap they set.